# Does a generator know about the generator function?

Tags: python, scope, reference, generator

Does the generator object returned from a generator function hold a reference to the function object at all?  In other words, is it possible to implement the `magic_fn` which can do this:

```
>>> def gen():
...     yield 1
...     yield 2
...     
>>> gen.attr = 'potato'
>>> g = gen()
>>> del gen
>>> next(g)
1
>>> magic_fn(g, 'attr')
'potato'
```

The generator has a reference to a code object (`g.gi_code`), a frame (`g.gi_frame`), and the name (`g.__name__`).  The code object even has the same memory address as `gen.__code__`.

However, assuming it hasn't already been garbage collected, I could not find a way to access the `gen.__dict__`.  Is it possible, or is the link already lost as soon as the generator was created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generator iterator does not refer to the generator function. You can see this by keeping a weak reference to the function, using [`weakref.ref`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html):

```
>>> import weakref
>>> def gen():
...     yield 1
...
>>> ref = weakref.ref(gen)
>>> gen_iter = gen()
>>> del gen
>>> ref() is None
True
```

Unlike normal references, a `weakref.ref` doesn't delay collection of what it refers to. If the referent (`gen`) was still alive, `ref()` would be `gen`. If the referent has been collected, `ref()` is `None`. As you can see, the weakref was cleared, which wouldn't happen if `gen_iter` still had a reference to `gen`.

Similarly, you can show that the generator iterator doesn't keep a reference to the function's `__dict__`, or any other reference chain that would let it retrieve items that were stored in the function's `__dict__`:

```
>>> class Dummy(object):
...     pass
...
>>> def gen():
...     yield 1
...
>>> gen.attr = Dummy()
>>> ref = weakref.ref(gen.attr)
>>> gen_iter = gen()
>>> del gen
>>> ref() is None
True
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also able to see it get collected by implementing a `__del__` on `Dummy` which prints 'goodbye'.   Could you add more explanation about this usage of `weakref.ref` and how it works?

Comment: @wim: Added a bit of explanation of weak references.